# Amort Table using javamoney 1.3 library

Tags: java, java-money, jsr354

I want to use javamoney for making an amort table for loans. 
I thought of using PresentValueOfAnnuityPayment but was unable to find it in javamoney 1.3.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I added this dependency in project but still am unable to find PresentValueOfAnnuityPayment or any other class from this https://github.com/JavaMoney/javamoney-lib/blob/master/calc/src/main/java/org/javamoney/calc/common/PresentValueOfAnnuityPayment.java repo

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javamoney.lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>javamoney-calc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and create a pom.xml file with dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
  <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: no it didnt help. still unable to find any methods which will help in making loan amortization table